# Codeship : Use Rails Fixtures with protractor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, codeship

I'm using Codeship to deploy my code.
I have a rails app with angularjs
Here's my problem, I have e2e tests with protractor. On local my tests are working fine but when I'm trying to deploy my code with codeship, the tests will not passed. I assume that my fixtures are not loaded and then my tests can't login into the app etc...
In my settings of codeship, I put this command to load my fixtures :

`bundle exec rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test`

But then It's not working, the fixture doesn't seem to load!

Is there any other way to load my fixtures? Or maybe try to seed my db with seeds?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to put `RAILS_ENV=test` in the beginning like: `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:fixtures:load`